# Cartan determinant of stable categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, determinants

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra with finitely many indecomposable non-projective modules $M_1, M_2,...,M_n$.

Let $a_{i,j}:=\dim(\underline{Hom_A}(M_j,M_i))$ (the dimension of the stable Homs betwee the modules) and $M_A$ the $n \times n$-matrix with entries $a_{i,j}$. This should be the Cartan matrix of the stable Auslander algebra of $A$.

> Question 1: Is the determinant of $M_A$ always greather than or equal to zero?

Note that a positive answer would especially prove the Cartan determinant conjecture for stable Auslander algebras.

> Question 2: Does the stable Auslander algebra have finite global dimension if and only if the determinant of $M_A$ is equal to one?

Question 1 is tested for many algebras, while question 2 is hard to test even with a computer but no counterexample was found yet.

edit: Here an example for representation-finite symmetric algebras suggested by computer experiments:

-Symmetric Nakayama algebras seems to have always $M_A=0$.

-The trivial extension of $D_n$ has $M_A=4,0,16,0,64$ for $n=4,5,6,7,8$.

-The trivial extension of $E_6$ has $M_A=0$.

-The trivial extension of $E_7$ has $M_A=64$.

-The trivial extension of $E_8$ has $M_A=256$.

-The penny farthing algebras $P_n$ have $M_A=16,0,1024,0,65536$ for $n=2,3,4,5,6$.

That are all representation-finite symmetric algebras up to stable equivalence. One might ask whether all $M_A$ are divisible by 4 and an explanation for this. (I have not yet found a representation-finite selfinjective algebra with $M_A$ not divisible by 4)